# Search multiple text files for specific lines of data and import into excel using VBA macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and I'm looking to use it to automate some of my processes. I have looked around this website (and others) and although I find very similar queries, I can't seem to find one that fits my needs exactly.

So far the closest thing I've found to what I'm looking to do is this: [Wanting to create a search field and button to trigger VBA script to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540162/wanting-to-create-a-search-field-and-button-to-trigger-vba-script-to-run)

I have a source folder with all my data. My data is stored in multiple text files. Here is an example of what the data in the files looks like:

```
10001,1,205955.00
10001,2,196954.00
10001,3,4.60
10001,4,92353.00
10001,5,85015.00
10001,6,255.90
10001,7,804.79
10001,8,205955.00
10001,9,32465.00
```

In each row, the first number is a geographic code, second number is a numeric code for a specific indicator (not important for what I'm trying to do), and the third number is the value I want to import into my spreadsheet. Each geographic code is associated with 2247 rows.

I want to use a search box control in Excel that I can type a specific geographic code into, click a button and then the macro would run, searching the files for that specific code and then importing all the values - in the order they are listed in the data file - into my desired range in the workbook.

So far I've gotten this code written. Again, forgive me if this is bad code... I tried to re-purpose the code from the other forum post I mentioned earlier.

I think I setup the import location right... I want it to import into column C, row 3 of the sheet that the search box/button combo will be present on. But now, I am unsure how I would get the import aspect to work. Thanks in advance for anyone who can help on this issue.

```
Sub SearchFolders()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim File As Object
Dim TS As Object
Dim SourceFolder As String
Dim Search As String
Dim LineNumber As Long
Dim DataSh As Worksheet

SourceFolder = "C:\Users\MarMar\Desktop\Data\Census2016\DataFiles\"
Search = TextBox1.Value

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolder)
Set DataSh = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3)

For Each File In Folder.Files
   Set TS = File.OpenAsTextStream()
   LineNumber = 0

      Do While Not TS.AtEndOfStream
      LineNumber = LineNumber + 1

      If InStr(TS.ReadLine, Search) Then

      'Code to Import Values to DataSh ???

      End If
      Loop

   TS.Close
   Next File

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Dim arr

For Each File In Folder.Files
    Set TS = File.OpenAsTextStream()
    LineNumber = 0

    Do While Not TS.AtEndOfStream

        arr = Split(TS.ReadLine, ",") 'split line to array

        'check first element in array
        If arr(0) = Search Then

            datash.Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
            Set datash = datash.Offset(1, 0)

        End If
    Loop

    TS.Close
Next File
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply! I tried your code but I keep getting the following two errors: 

Compile Error: Method or data member not found. 
Compile Error: Expected array

Forgive me for the noobness but I think I am not doing the dim arr part right - I am not sure what to put it as, long, variant, string? None of them seem to work?

Comment: On which line?  `arr` can be declared exactly as shown, or you can add "As Variant"  if you want (same thing though)

Comment: It gives the "method or data member not found" error and highlights the resize and offset sections.

Comment: @MarMarSuperstar I'm surprised you didn't get an error before that line. In your original code, you declare `DataSh` as a worksheet, but then set it to a Range object.  I'm surprised that Set statement didn't return a `Type Mismatch` error. But that might be your problem anyway.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Hi Ron! Oh ya, you're right. Nice catch. Okay so now that I've changed it to a range, it works! But instead of just inputting the third row of data from my data text files, it inputs all three numbers, what am I missing to make that happen.

Comment: @MarMarSuperstar Huh? Third Row?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sorry I meant column, wow my bad. I have many rows in my source text files, but each row has three columns of data. The current code as is imports all three columns, where I only want to import the third column of data. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: @MarMarSuperstar Tim Williams code shows that `arr` has your line split by commas.  You are checking the first element for `Search`. You'd want the last element for your value.  Look at VBA Help for the `Split` function so you understand exactly what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on what I should be looking up! I figured it out. :) I posted the final code so that anyone else who wants to do something similar will have reference. Thanks so much TimWilliams and RonRosenfeld !!

Answer (score 0):

Final result that worked for me!

```
Sub SearchImportData1()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFolder As String
Dim Folder As Object
Dim Import As Range
Dim Search As String
Dim TextBox1 As TextBox
Dim File As Object
Dim TS As Object
Dim LineNumber As Integer
Dim Arr As Variant

SourceFolder = "C:\Users\MarMar\Desktop\Data\Census2016\DataFiles\"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolder)
Set Import = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3)

Search = ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text

For Each File In Folder.Files

    Set TS = File.OpenAsTextStream()
    LineNumber = 0

      Do While Not TS.AtEndOfStream

      Arr = Split(TS.ReadLine, ",")

         If Arr(0) = Search Then
         Import.Resize(1, 1).Value = Arr(2)
         Set Import = Import.Offset(1, 0)
         End If

      Loop

    TS.Close
    Next File

End Sub
```